# Checkbox in PHP using MySQL Data

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm coding some code for a platform, and im a bit stuck right now because one "simple" step.

This page's platform is meant to be an "edit task", where an user can edit some options of the task; the changes are sent after the edition.

The problem is, i want to do a checkbox that fills with members name; that i can do right now; but i want to add some check options for the members that already are checked.

Per exemple: "Sara", "Luis", "Pedro", and i already checked the two first ones, and i want to add the third. I need to see that the first two ones are already inserted, and changing the check mark will add/remove from the tasks row table.

I don't know if that is possible.

Right now i have this code:

```
<?php
include("ligacao_metodos.php");

$get=mysql_query("SELECT Nome FROM utilizadores ORDER BY Nome DESC");
?>

    Pessoas:

     <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
            {
            ?>              <input type="checkbox" name="Nome" value="<?php echo($row['Nome'])?>" > <?php echo($row['Nome']) ?>


                <?php
            }               
        ?>
```

Comment: For this to work without submitting the form to PHP and causing a page refresh, you will need to use Javascript in AJAX-style

Comment: Can u suggest me how? @SyntaxLAMP

Answer (score 0):

If it's already checked, it should be someway saved in your database.

You need to also select the field from the database where it says it's checked, or not.

```
 <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
        { $checked = "";
if ($row['check']) $checked = "checked";?>
                     <input type="checkbox" name="Nome" value="<?php echo($row['Nome'])?>"<?php echo($checked) ?> > <?php echo($row['Nome']) ?>


            <?php
        }               
    ?>
```

If it's checked, a variable set will write down the checked state, needed to set the checkbox to checked.

EDIT:

Select Join Approach:

```
mysqli_query("SELECT utilizadores.nome, tarefas.checked FROM Orders INNER JOIN Tarefas ON Utilizadores.ID=Tarefas.ID");
```

Assuming that the ID of each one is correspondent, use whatever information you created to inform wich one is the user checked.

OBS: Neither the join or the ajax approach will work if you have any correlation in beetween the tables, since you will have nothing to tell what name is already cheked.

Comment: It will not set the check mark, since i'm getting this names from "utilizadores" (users) table, and the list of "checked members" are set in the "tarefas" (tasks) table. The real question is how can i manage the checked when i have a row in tarefas that storage the members checked and i need to retrieve all the users for add/remove. @Hotwer

Comment: Well, you can do two things now, since you can also do a join SQL call, or an ajax call to reconfigure the already done page, with Javascript. The join call would be anything like "SELECT Utilizados.Nome, Tarefas.Checked 
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Tarefas
ON Utilizadores.ID=Tarefas.ID;"
I will edit the post for the ajax example too.

Comment: Can u show me some example of that in the code above?